# Selecting only first part of Amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table (actually this is result of the query)
[image]

Wht I want is to come up with the following table

[image]

It assigns zero to amount for each code value except for the first one.

Any strategies to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your query to get this result look like? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need the amounts with 0 ? Else you could use `Group by Code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
declare @tab table(
       code int, 
       amount int)

insert into @tab values
    (1,100),
    (1,100),
    (1,100),
    (2,500),
    (2,500),
    (3,1000);

    select code, 
       case when rn=1 then 
           amount 
       else 0 end amount 
    from 
 (select *, 
          row_number()Over(partition by code Order by amount) RN 
      from @tab)t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number()` to identify the first row for each `code`. From there on, it's just a simple `case` expression:

```
SELECT code, CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS amount
FROM   (SELECT code, amount, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY amount) AS rn
        FROM   my_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Code,CASE When RN > 1 Then 0 Else Amount
FROM
(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by Code Order by (Select Null)) RN
   FROM Table1
) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select Code, 
    case when ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Code Order by Amount)=1 then Amount else 0 end Amount
From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please , update table with account at below query:

```
SELECT A.code, 
       ( CASE 
          WHEN A.rno = 1 THEN B.amount 
          ELSE 0 
        END ) AS amount 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                OVER( 
                  partition BY code 
                  ORDER BY code DESC) AS rno, 
              code 
       FROM   account) AS A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT C.code, 
                               Sum(C.amount) AS amount 
                        FROM   account C 
                        GROUP  BY C.code) AS B 
                    ON B.code = A.code
```